# How to split perl programm over multiple files

Tags: perl

How do I use functionality written in a different file, but not located in an `@INC` location, but relative to the main executable? I want to be able to distribute the entire directory and have it be executable everywhere (assuming third-party libraries are already installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FindBin to get the [location](https://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin) of your main executable and [lib](https://perldoc.perl.org/lib) to add directories to your `@INC` that are based on your main directory.

A common example would be if your libraries were in a `/lib` directory below the directory that contains your main program.

```
use FindBin '$RealBin';
use lib "$RealBin/lib";

# You can then load your own modules from /lib
use My::Module;
```

Comment: There is no way to avoid having to put that atop every file?

Comment: @Philippe: That's probably the safest approach. But any mechanism for manipulating `@INC` will work. I guess you could also look at setting the `PERL5LIB` environment variable. See [How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-%28%40INC%29-at-runtime%3F)